# How to make (Bash's) column respect quoted text (file names)

Tags: bash

I want to make column respect quoted column entries in order to optimise space.

cat testfile

```
123     "file name with spaces" tail
51    "longfilenamehere with spaces" head 
Monday "shortname" hands
Blue "very longfilename_______________here with spaces" feet
```

Version with "column" which only respects spaces as column separators, the width of each column being determined by the widest entry

cat testfile | column -t

```
123     "file              name                             with     spaces"  tail
51      "longfilenamehere  with                             spaces"           head     
Monday  "shortname"                                                           hands                                              
Blue    "very              longfilename_______________here  with     spaces"  feet
```

Whereas what I want is

```
123     "file name with spaces"                            tail
51      "longfilenamehere with spaces"                     head
Monday  "shortname"                                        hands
Blue    "very longfilename_______________here with spaces" feet
```

Comment: Simple hack would be `<testfile sed 's/ /./g' | column -t | sed 's/\./ /g'`

Comment: For what it's worth,`column` has nothing to do with `bash`.  It's an independent executable.

Comment: @erik258 Aha... I couldn't find a "column" tag, maybe you have the points to add one (I don't)

Comment: Can your quoted text ever contain quotes, e.g. `"this ""is"" here"` or `"this \"is\" here"`?

Comment: @Ed The actual senario is using file names and as I copy to FAT32 drives sometimes I don't have that problem. I'll test it though. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` is capable of parsing quotes. It could take arguments and pass them to `printf` to output nicely separated output that could be feed to column.

```
$ cat testfile  | xargs printf '%s|"%s"|%s\n' | column -t -s'|'
123     "file name with spaces"                             tail
51      "longfilenamehere with spaces"                      head
Monday  "shortname"                                         hands
Blue    "very longfilename_______________here with spaces"  feet
```

Comment: You mean `< testfile xargs printf ... | column`.  `xargs` does not require a `cat` process as a file-reading agent.

Comment: @KamilCuk Super - that works wonderfully - thank you!

Comment: Stating  the obvious - that would fail if the input contained a `|` (ditto for any other character or string you choose to use as the separator).